# I have error in Xcode 11.3 when archive the project

Tags: swift, xcode11.3

My project is build successfully and I can run it on my device without any error but when I archive the project I found these errors:

[image]

I am using Xcode 11.3

Comment: When you build and run on your device, are you using "Release" settings?  (If not, try that.)  Can you show code for one of the errors it's reporting so we can see what it might be upset about?

Comment: he cannot read my helper classes when release

Comment: I don't know what your "helper" classes are or how they're referenced.

Comment: my web service class